# Illustrator: Change tool shortcuts to use a non-input key combination

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface, adobe-illustrator, usability, ux

### The problem

I'm tired of accidentally typing "v" and "a" characters into my text boxes when what I really want to do is switch to one of the selection tools (because their default shortcuts are <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd>).

I would like all of the Selection tools, as well as the Type tool to have keyboard shortcuts that cannot be mistaken for text input.

[image]

However, for some reason Adobe really wants to prevent users from doing this.

### What I've tried

When I try assigning a Function Key I get the following error:

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is not explicitly mentioned, so maybe that will work? Nope. When I try assigning a shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> I get this error instead:

[image]

And of course <kbd>Shift</kbd> won't be of any help, since that will just result in *uppercase* unwanted letters in my text boxes.

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> as soon as I'm finished typing will break out out of the text box, and is a good "best practice". But I would still feel more at ease if I could make the tool shortcuts less hazardous.

**Does anyone know of a workaround for these pointless limitations in Illustrator's shortcut customization options?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you willing to settle for two keystrokes? If yes, Assign a function key to an action that `deselects all` and then use either `A` or `V` to choose the tool you want.